# dplyr / tidyr summaries two columns into a single named list column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Imagine this data frame:

```
df <- tibble(
  key = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3), rep(3, 3)),
  date = rep(Sys.Date(), 9),
  hour = rep(c('00', '01', '02'), 3),
  value = rep(c(8, 9, 10), 3)
  )
```

I want output such that the group summary column is a named list of hour and value. Same as if I were to do this, for each group:

```
as.list(setNames(df$value[df$key == 1], df$hour[df$key == 1]))
$`00`
[1] 8

$`01`
[1] 9

$`02`
[1] 10
```

Something along these lines, but something that actually works:

```
df %>%
  group_by(key, date) %>%
  summarise(
    daily_value = sum(value),
    hourly_values = as.list(setNames(value, hour))
    )
```

Open to a `nest` or similar tidyr solution as well.

EDIT: Output should be same as what is produced here:

```
outputDf <- df %>%
  group_by(key, date) %>%
  summarise(daily_value = sum(value))

outputDf$hourly_value <- list(
  as.list(setNames(df$value[df$key == 1], df$hour[df$key == 1])),
  as.list(setNames(df$value[df$key == 2], df$hour[df$key == 2])),
  as.list(setNames(df$value[df$key == 3], df$hour[df$key == 3]))
  )

outputDf
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   key [?]
    key       date daily_value hourly_value
  <dbl>     <date>       <dbl>       <list>
1     1 2019-06-18          27   <list [3]>
2     2 2019-06-18          27   <list [3]>
3     3 2019-06-18          27   <list [3]>

outputDf$hourly_value
[[1]]
[[1]]$`00`
[1] 8

[[1]]$`01`
[1] 9

[[1]]$`02`
[1] 10


[[2]]
[[2]]$`00`
[1] 8

[[2]]$`01`
[1] 9

[[2]]$`02`
[1] 10


[[3]]
[[3]]$`00`
[1] 8

[[3]]$`01`
[1] 9

[[3]]$`02`
[1] 10
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave an example of the desired output. Not sure what you are looking for when you say, "group summary column is a named list of hour and value".

Comment: I wan't each cell of the output column to be as the output of `as.list(setNames(df$value[df$key == 1], df$hour[df$key == 1]))` is.

Comment: you could use `map()` from `purrr` to create the a list column, then just assign names to the list column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to wrap with a `list` as `summarise` expects to return a single row per group.  With `as.list`, it would be a `list` with `length` same as the number of rows of the group.  By wrapping it as a `list`, we make sure that the length is 1 for `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)  
df %>% 
   group_by(key, date) %>% 
   summarise(daily_value = sum(value), 
              hourly_values = list(as.list(setNames(value, hour))))
```

Comment: That does the trick. I had thought `as.list` would return a list. Can you help me understand why the need to wrap in another `list` call?

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- tibble(
  key = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3), rep(3, 3)),
  date = rep(Sys.Date(), 9),
  hour = rep(c('00', '01', '02'), 3),
  value = rep(c(8, 9, 10), 3)
)

df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(key, date) %>% 
  mutate(daily_value = sum(value),
  hourly_value = as.list(value)) #create a list column

names(df2$hourly_value) <- df$hour #give names to the list column
```